# How to count instance of item in relation to a person on Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to count the instance of each item bought by a person. The first column contains the person's name, the second contains the item, and the third would contain the **formula** that I would need to keep track of the instance of that item for that person.

For example:

```
    John       Apple        1
    John       Apple        2
    Mary       Banana       1
    John       Apple        3
    Mary       Apple        1
    John       Banana       1
    Mary       Apple        2
    John       Apple        4
    Mary       Apple        3
```

I would appreciate any help you can give. For context, I want to understand how to do this so that I can apply it to a similar problem that I need to solve for work (I would be tracking the instances of different types doors built by different people).

Comment: Try `COUNTIFS()` with ranges like `$A$1:$A1` so that only part of it updates as you copy / paste it down. For instance, the third row would update to `$A$1:$A3`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the Pivot Table.

Based on your sample, you may create a pivot table like following.

[image]

Then right-click the pivot table > PivotTable Options > Total and Filters tab > Untick the boxes of Grand Totals.

[image]

And then choose this pivot table > Design tab > Substotals > Do not show Substotals.

[image]

Continue to click Report Layout > Show in Tabular Form.

[image]

Please check whether the result is your needs.

[image]